# How do I create a cloud?

Tags: server, cloud

So I am kind of new at this,but I have my mind set on creating a cloud. By cloud I mean a place where I can store file and access them from anywhere, like Dropbox or Google Drive. I cant really find a step by step guide on what I need to do in order to create one. I have an old computer that I would like to use but  I don't know how to set everything up. If I will need more than one computer I can get that, although i would like to use only one if possible. By the way i am not looking for a software program, such as OwnCloud or others, I am looking for an operating system.

Comment: Do you want to be able to access these files from anywhere, or just from home. If you want to access them from anywhere do you have a static IP address? Cloud is a marketing buzz word for a server whose files, resources, applications.. that you can access from any location. So it really depends on your specific needs.

Comment: What OSes do you want to be able to access your files from? Windows? Ubuntu? Mac?

Comment: What is the issue with using Google Drive and the like?

Comment: I want to be able to access my file from any where and hopefully any OS as I want to just have to access a website type of format. Also, the problem with Google Drive is: 1. There is a limit 2. I am not in control of my data they are. Also is there anyway to make one without having a static IP

Answer (score 1):

Cloud is just a term file hosting companies use to differentiate themselves from pirating file hosts. Cloud meaning the file hosting service is typically intended as a place for the user to backup all their personal files rather than share files with others.

Your question is a rather loaded one, but lets break it down in terms of what you'd need.

**List Of Things:**

- A computer to host the files (aka server).
- An ip address for the computer, and if desired a domain name. [So you can access the computer over the net. If you plan to use a domain name with your site eg: http://example.per.red then you'll probably want a static ip for ease though there are a few services that can help you use a dynamic ip for webhosting. If you plan to access the site over the internet keep in mind the bandwidth limits of your internet plan.]
- Ubuntu with Lamp installed, or some kind of OS setup with a web server program. [Lamp will add web hosting capability to your Ubuntu installation so you can host a website. You can use the server or desktop version of Ubuntu it doesn't matter.]
- A website [This part will be tricky because it needs to support browsing files, uploading files, allow the user to download files, and most importantly secure the whole thing. You'll either have to find a file hosting website script, buy one like YetiShare, or make one yourself (php html etc). If you use a site script built by someone else it may require you to have a domain name rather than just an ip.]

You can setup a Local cloud server for use only in your house, or you can setup one to be over the internet for use anywhere. If your plan is the internet then it would probably be cheaper to just purchase vps hosting rather than shell out for a static ip and bandwidth for it.